# Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' in react native ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm receiving this error message after install dependencies.

```
node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/NavigationContainer.tsx: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
```

and here is my package.json

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8psI.png)

does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 npm install react-native-reanimated
```

try this command and run it again.

follow the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.

Comment: no, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you try deleting node modules and reinstalling again.

Comment: yes and i reinstall the pod too.